# Combine list of items, but keep amount value into separate columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of Product Sales from 2013 and want to compare this to Product Sales in 2014.

There are new products in 2014 and some older products removed from 2013.
Thus, the list of alphabetized items do not line up between the two years.

I only know how to merge the item list and remove duplicates but this doesn't help me with the Sales Amount for each corresponding year.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Say we start with data like:

[image]

some items have been dropped and other items added.

1. copy cols **A** and **C** into col **E**
2. use the *RemoveDuplicates* feature in the **Data** tab
3. use the *Sort* feature in the **Home** tab

In **F2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(E2,A$2:A$7,0)),"")
```

and copy down.  In **G2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$7,MATCH(E2,C$2:C$7,0)),"")
```

and copy down.  We now have:

[image]

and we can directly compare cols **F** and **G**.